# How to close an openGL window

Tags: c, opengl, freeglut

Here, I have two loops. The first loop processes the graphics for a few seconds and then the code goes to the second loop. I process the graphical events via `glutMainLoopEvent` in the first loop. Before the second loop starts, I would like to close the graphic window. It seems the command `glutLeaveMainLoop` cannot close the window. What other function should I use to force the window closed right after the first loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> // for sleep

void cback_render()
{
    if(!glutGetWindow())
        return ;
    static float rotations = 0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(rotations, 0, 0, 1);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);
        glVertex3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(0,1,0);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    if (++rotations > 360) rotations -= 360;
}

void timer(int )
{
    if(!glutGetWindow())
        return ;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutMainLoopEvent();
    glutTimerFunc(30, timer, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);

    glutCreateWindow("freegluttest");
    glutDisplayFunc (cback_render);
    glutTimerFunc(30, timer, 1);

    long i=0;
    while(glutGetWindow() && i< 30)
    {
        printf("[%ld]\n",i);
        i++;
        glutMainLoopEvent();
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100) );
    }
    glutMainLoopEvent();

    glutLeaveMainLoop(); // does not work
    glutMainLoopEvent();

    // do something else ....
    while(1)
    {
        // other calculations
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this glut or freeglut? I'm confused with the glut tag.

Comment: @CroCo, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with freeglut but are you sure it is Ok to call this "glutMainLoopEvent()" after terminating "glutLeaveMainLoop()"? Also, have you tried to terminate the Window by clicking the x mark button ?

Comment: @CroCo, any other solution than `freeglut` is welcome. closing window by clicking on x mark is totally possible. while I am looking for a way to close the window by the code rather than by user.

Comment: Well there are numerous solutions such as GLFW and SDL2 but it seems to me that you misuse the library or the way you implement those threads need to be modified.

Comment: @CroCo, by misuse, do you mean not using `glutMainLoop`? the reason is that in a bigger application, I need to have total control on the flow of the program rather than leaving the control to glut main loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok from the freeglut docs at http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#EventProcessing

The function you are using `glutLeaveMainLoop()` is to simply stop the glut's main loop, if it is started by `glutMainLoop()` not `glutMainLoopEvent()`.

Since you are controlling the loop yourself in your example, `glutLeaveMainLoop()` won't do anything.

> It is intended to leave glut's main loop IF glut is controlling it not you.

Since you have a `while(1)` at the end with a 100ms sleep, the app will do nothing else when it gets there after all the frames have been rendered. If you want to destroy the window use some window function like `glutDestroyWindow()`.

Comment: I think `glutDestroyWindow()` is for adding a callback. I dont think it destroys the window.  The second loop stands for my program will do another computations. I cannot remove the second loop. I strictly need to close the window without termination of the program.

Comment: are you sure what version of GLUT are your using? check this link it says the function `glutDestroyWindow()` does exactly what I think. https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node19.html

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The code worked using:

`if(glutGetWindow())
   glutDestroyWindow(glutGetWindow());
 glutMainLoopEvent();
 glutMainLoopEvent();`

Comment: Of course you need to get the window id and send it to the function `void glutDestroyWindow(int winID)`. Glad it helped.